# Rspec request modifications ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

For some time now i experience, that request modifications are beeing ignored by the controller specs.

the spec_helper is, for the purpose of finding the error, condensed to

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require "webmock/rspec"

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

the controller spec itself looks like this (ignoring the other contexts)

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rest-client'

describe SessionsController, :type => :controller do
  describe '#create' do
    it 'should [something]' do
      session[:return_point] = root_path
      post :create, {:sessions => {:email => 'foo@bar.com', :password => :123}}
    end
  end
end
```

and the sessions_controller is condensed to

```
class SessionsController < GuestBaseController
  def create
    raise session.inspect
  end
end
```

The result of this raise within the spec is `{}`, which is obviously wrong, since i just put something into the session.

To the question part:
Did i fail to set some config variable which does the session magic / mock and stub magic?

I have the same problem with `request.cookies` and `response.cookies`.
I can set them, but they are ignored.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

In controller specs you can modify the session that is part of the `request` object or you can pass it as a 2nd hash to the request message:

```
request.session[:return_point] = root_path
get :index, {}, { another_session: 'is merged with the request session' }
```